# Which one should I choose (black jack)

Tags: statistics

I think this is a simple problem....

I'm wondering which one of these options will give the highest payout rate.  The following statistics are based on a game similar to black jack but not exactly the same.

If I win I get double my money back if I lose I get nothing.  How would I calculate which set of "rules" (Hitting on 16 no ace/Hitting on 16 ace thing) to choose.  Note that the odds of each scenario were calculated with a program I made that ran the scenario 10 million times.

Option 1

```
Hitting on 16 no ace
Hitting on 16 ace

23.8% get a 17 and give 10.6% winning chance 
23.8%  get a 18 and give 21.8% winning chance 
23.8% get a 19 and give 41.2% winning chance 
12.7% get a 20 and give 65.0% winning chance 
11.5% get a 21 and give 100% winning chance 
4.5% of the time bust
```

Option 2

```
Hitting on 16 no ace
Hitting on 17 ace

4.5% get a 17 and give 10.6% winning chance 
27.7%  get a 18 and give 21.8% winning chance 
27.8% get a 19 and give 41.2% winning chance 
16.6% get a 20 and give 65.0% winning chance 
15.4% get a 21 and give 100% winning chance 
8.1% of the time bust
```

Option 3

```
Hitting on 17 no ace
Hitting on 17 ace

28.2%  get a 18 and give 21.8% winning chance 
28.3% get a 19 and give 41.2% winning chance 
17.0% get a 20 and give 65.0% winning chance 
15.8% get a 21 and give 100% winning chance 
10.6% of the time bust
```

Option 4

```
Hitting on 17 no ace
Hitting on 18 ace

7.3%  get a 18 and give 21.8% winning chance 
33.1% get a 19 and give 41.2% winning chance 
22.0% get a 20 and give 65.0% winning chance 
20.8% get a 21 and give 100% winning chance 
16.9% of the time bust
```

Option 5

```
Hitting on 16 no ace
Hitting on 18 ace

8.9% get a 17 and give 10.6% winning chance 
6.3%  get a 18 and give 21.8% winning chance 
32.1% get a 19 and give 41.2% winning chance 
21.0% get a 20 and give 65.0% winning chance 
19.8% get a 21 and give 100% winning chance 
1.2% of the time bust
```

And also how would I calculate the payout rate of the best option?

Thanks (tell me if I need to add anything please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the probability by the winning chance for each outcome and then add it all up. The option with the highest sum is the one you should choose.

For example, with option one:

$23.8\% \cdot 10.6\% = 0.025228 $
$23.8\% \cdot 21.8\% = 0.051884 $
$23.8\% \cdot 41.2\% = 0.098056 $
$12.7\% \cdot 65.0\% = 0.082550 $
$11.5\% \cdot 100\%  = 0.115000 $
$4.5\% \cdot 0\% = 0$

Now add all these up to get that you have a $37.2718\%$ chance of winning using option 1.

Comment: So for the first option I got about 37.3, does this mean I will win 37.3% of the time using that option?
Ops you just answered that, thanks :)

Comment: Yes. (I just edited my post before you added the comment. :)